# Какое значение имеет изменение состояния в mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть условный пример:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { val } = state
  const valName = val.name && ''
  return { valName }
}
```

Здесь получаться мы проверяем наличие `val.name` и передаем нужное значение пропсом в компонент. Первый вопрос: есть ли разница, где делать эту проверку, внутри `mapStateToProps` или внутри метода `render` самого компонента? Ведь удобно сразу получить в компонент нужное значение, `mapStateToProps` просто же функция, какая разница где она вызовется.

Второй вопрос:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { val } = state
  return {
     filtredName: val.filter(el => el.name === 'name')
  }
}
```

Такое код мы во-первых можем оптимизировать например библиотекой `reselect`, чтобы смотреть изменился объект или нет. Тогда состояние не изменится и `render` не будет вызван. Но если мы будем делать фильтр в `render`, то у нас на вход могут быть разные состояния `val`, а после фильтра всегда одинаковые. Получается будет вызван `render` где-то лишний раз, пока мы не отфильтруем массив, и не проверим изменился ли он.

Объясните если я что-то неправильно сказал и сформулировал.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос 1: Пустая строка это способ **отобразить** неизвестное значение, лучше **отображать** в render.

Вопрос 2: Храните значение фильтра в redux состоянии, либо в url...

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  // state.filter - значение из redux состояния
  // props.match.params.filter - значение от react-router к примеру.
}
```

или с селектором

```
const selector = createSelector(
  (_, props) => props.match.params.filter,
  (state) => state.name,
  (filter, state) => { ... },
);
```

Лучше не использовать state компонента для такого.

Comment: `лучше отображать в render`
Поясните чем лучше? Вопрос как раз не про пустую строку, а о том где лучше делать вычисление и проверку.

Второй ответ не совсем понял. То-есть если у нас есть например данные в `state.data` и мы хотим их отфильтровать то должны хранить в state ещё и отфильтрованное состояние? Получается мы храним оригинальное состояние и фильтрованное? Если я правильно понял. Но в случае когда нам нужен фильтр, есть шанс что оригинально состояние вообще не понадобится и будет просто так хранится в state. Поясните подробнее, спасибо.

Comment: Если на примере... Есть такой роут
`/data`
добавить ещё один
`/data/:filter`
и теперь если пользователь фильтрует напимер по deleted
`/data/deleted`
получается что часть состояние приложение хранится в url. Это намного лучше, чем если бы оно хранилось в state компонента.

Comment: Вы храните состояние и значение фильтр. А перед тем как показать фильтруете лишнее на текущий момент. Конкретно в примере с фильтром лучше всего его значение хранить в url.